# Array at index within the size of array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to create an array initialized to the length of an object. Then be able to insert new data into an index within the array.

Code example:

```
$scope.holder = new Array($scope.x.length);
$scope.holder[0].new_data = response.data;
```

However the above will give error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set 'new_data' of undefined
```

How can this be if I specified the size of the array? Is the array not meant to have three objects in it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$scope.holder[0]` is not defined yet, array has three undefined items

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.holder = new Array($scope.x.length);
$scope.holder[0] = {'new_data':  response.data};
```

**UPD**: Or you can create array of objects

```
$scope.holder = Array.apply(null, Array($scope.x.length)).map(function () { return new Object(); })
$scope.holder[0].new_data = response.data;
```

Comment: Works aswell thank you! ai jai jai such silly things

Answer (score 3):

In this case first `[0]` element in `Array` must be `Object` because now it is `undefined` and you can not assign property to `undefined`, you need create empty `Object` (`{}`) and then assign properties to it

```
$scope.holder = new Array($scope.x.length);
$scope.holder[0] = {};
$scope.holder[0].new_data = response.data;
```